# Flash AS3 how to reset drag and drop game?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am working on a Drag and Drop game in AS3.
How to reset its positions when a new game starts?
I am not good at English T T

[image: code]

Comment: Do not use code screenshots in questions, period.

Answer (score 1):

well its highly depended on how you're game is developed but an easy way is to have an array on the document class that contains all the positions and initialize the position when beginning a new game

Comment: can you guide it for me?

Comment: the screenshots in your question is not loading for me , please type it in your question .